# When renaming a file with PowerShell, how do I handle filenames with "["?

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I'm running this PowerShell command:

```
Get-ChildItem .\tx\*.htm | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '\.htm','.tmp'}
```

and receive the following error when a filename contains square brackets -- `[` and/or `]` --, understandable since those have a meaning within the PowerShell syntax.

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\users\xxxxx\desktop\tx\
Foofoofoofoo_foo_foo_[BAR]_Foofoofoofoo_foofoofoo.htm' does not exist.
At C:\users\xxxxx\desktop\foo002.ps1:59 char:39
+ Get-ChildItem .\tx\*.htm | Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.htm','.tmp' }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

All the other files in the path have similar names (`Phrase_With_Underscores.htm`), and are renamed without incident. Anyone have any experience with this and know how to counter it so I can manipulate these files?

Comment: shouldn't it be -replace '.htm'?? why is there a "\" in there?

Comment: @D3vtr0n try this: `"shtm.htm" -replace '.htm', '.jpg'`

Comment: @Christian what is this character defined as?

Comment: @D3vtr0n first argument of `-replace` is a regex value, `\\` is the escape character for regex. That's all ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can workaround using `move-item` for renaming items using the parameter `-LiteralPath`.

Is a know bug: [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/277707/rename-item-fails-when-renaming-a-file-and-the-filename-contains-brackets) *(read Keith Hill Comment for: powershell V3 fix this issue)*

Comment: A bug? From Microsoft? Perish the thought! :)

Comment: [system.io.file]::Move($fullname,$newfullname)

Comment: @D3vtr0n `move-item` is more posh :)

Comment: This was a known bug in PowerShell v1 & v2.  It has been fixed in v3 by the addition of the -LiteralPath parameter to Rename-Item.