# PowerShell: I need to understand why parameters are interpreted as NULL

Tags: powershell, nullreferenceexception, file-rename

I'm getting an error that I can't call a method on a null valued expression. However, I'm not sure WHY the parameters are resulting in a null value. I need a second set of eyes to look at this and give me some guidance.

```
$docpath = "c:\users\x\desktop\do"
$htmPath = "c:\users\x\desktop\ht"
$txtPath = "c:\users\x\desktop\tx"
$srcPath = "c:\users\x\desktop\ht"
#
$srcfilesTXT = Get-ChildItem $txtPath -filter "*.htm*"
$srcfilesDOC = Get-ChildItem $docPath -filter "*.htm*"
$srcfilesHTM = Get-ChildItem $htmPath -filter "*.htm*"
#
function rename-documents ($docs) {  
    Move-Item -txtPath $_.FullName $_.Name.Replace("\.htm", ".txt") 
    Move-Item -docpath $_.FullName $_.Name.Replace("\.htm", ".doc") 
}
ForEach ($doc in $srcpath) {
    Write-Host "Renaming :" $doc.FullName         
    rename-documents -docs  $doc.FullName   
    $doc = $null   
}
```

And the error....

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\users\x\desktop\foo002.ps1:62 char:51
+     Move-Item -txtPath $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace <<<< ("\.htm", ".txt")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Replace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\users\x46332\desktop\foo002.ps1:63 char:51
+     Move-Item -docpath $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace <<<< ("\.htm", ".doc")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Replace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

First: it appears that my `("\.htm", ".txt")` is what's showing up as null. I've tried it without the `\` - `(".htm", ".txt")` - as well and received the same results.

Second: syntactically, I'm interpreting my line as `move-item <path> <source-file-passed-to-function> <replacement=name-for-file> (parameters-for-replacement)`. Is that an appropriate understanding of what this code is doing?

Third: Do I need to have a `-literalpath` parameter in there somewhere? MS TechNet and get-help have very little information on the uses of the `-literalpath` parameter; I was unable to find something relevant to my particular situation.

Help me understand what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: First: `$srcpath` contain "c:\users\x\desktop\ht" as string and not a list of file. Second: for your `move-item` this -> `-txtpath` is the name of the file to move and not the path. Describe what exactly is your goal in your question.

Comment: third: `-literalpath` is needed in `move-item` as per your precedent question http://stackoverflow.com/a/14259748/520612

Comment: GOAL: I am trying to rename a batch of files from *.foo to *.bar. Renaming must be a function in a script. The script already has path variables set up which need to be passed into the function.

Comment: Try follow @keithill answer, it puts on the right way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of a simple function `$_` is not defined.  `$_` is only valid in a pipeline.  That is, `$_` reprensents the current object being passed down the pipeline.

With your current function definition try it this way:

```
function Rename-HtmlDocument([System.IO.FileInfo]$docs, $newExt) {  
    $docs | Move-Item -Dest {$_.FullName -replace '\.htm$', $newExt} 
}
```

You can pass this function the `$srcfilesDOC` and `$srcFilesTXT` variables directly e.g.:

```
Rename-HtmlDocument $srcFilesDOC .doc
Rename-HtmlDocument $srcFilesTXT .txt
```

Of course you could make this more generic and get the source extension from the FileInfo object e.g.:

```
function Rename-DocumentExtension([System.IO.FileInfo]$docs, $newExt) {  
    $docs | Move-Item -Dest {$_.FullName.Replace($_.Extension, $newExt)} 
}
```

BTW PowerShell's Move-Item command doesn't have the parameters you're using `-txtPath` and `-docPath`. Is this a function you've created?

Comment: -txtPath and -docPath were SUPPOSED to be $txtPath and $docPath (as defined above), which is part of the problem, I'm sure. I'm going to mess around with your solution. It looks like it may work for me, given the script I have to work with.

Comment: here's where this all started: stackoverflow.com/a/14259748/520612 and now that I'm looking at your solution, RenameItem ~may~ not work.

Comment: There is no need to escape the dot in `.Replace("…","…")`, it would be required in the first argument when using `-replace "…","…"`, since it is then treated as a regex. That is also why I would prefer the latter, since you can then add a trailing `$` because you mean to replace only the extension (at the very end).

Comment: To change ONLY the filename extension, • add a `$` at the end of a replace _regex_, • use `.BaseName` (excludes drive, folder and extension), or • use `[IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(…)`

Comment: @mousio Good point on the `$` metachar.  I also like just using `[IO.Path]::ChangeExtension()`.  There are many ways to skin this cat in PowerShell.

Comment: @mousio is right on escaping the dot.  In fact, escaping the dot makes it not work.  This works for me: `"Somekindafile.html".Replace(".htm",".txt")`.  This does not: `"Somekindafile.html".Replace("\.htm",".txt")`

Comment: This should be using `-replace` which uses regex instead of `String.Replace()` anyway.